# Utilizar caminho selecionado no listdir

Tags: python, tkinter

estou começando a aprender python (na verdade é minha primeira linguagem kk).

Trabalho com fotos e tenho um projeto desenvolver uma ferramenta de renomeio de fotos, porém estou com uma dificuldade pra integrar algumas partes do código.
Vê se conseguem me ajudar:

---

A ferramenta possui 4 botões:

- Selecionar Lista (Aqui selecionamos uma lista em .txt)
- Selecionar Diretório (Aqui vamos escolher onde rodar o código de separar e renomear)
- Separar (Aqui rodamos uma parte do código que separa em uma pasta as fotos que consta na lista)
- Renomear (Aqui rodamos a parte do código responsável por renomear as fotos separadas de acordo com a lista criada)

---

Atualmente tenho que copiar o arquivo python pra dentro do diretório e ele busca os arquivos se baseando nos parâmetros definidos pro diretório onde ele se encontra. A ideia seria rodar o python em um unico lugar e ele rodar em outros diretórios.

Minha dificuldade está em colocar os diretórios de lista e diretórios dentro dos códigos que separam e renomeiam

O código está um pouco extenso, mas segue ele abaixo:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


janela = tk.Tk()

def traco():
    print('-'*70)


#____________________________________________________________________
#INFORMAÇÕES INICIAIS



janela.title('Renamer Book v.2.0')
janela.geometry('500x600')

#____________________________________________________________________
#INSTRUÇÕES


frase1 = Label(janela, text="Para que o Renamer Book funcione, a lista deverá seguir a seguinte estrutura:")
frase1.place(x=50, y=100)

frase2 = Label(janela, text="nomeoriginal.extensão + ponto e vígula +     novonome.extensão")
frase2.place(x=80, y=120)

frase3 = Label(janela, text="EX: IMG2589.jpg;guilherme-micheletti-mc-IMG2589.jpg")
frase3.place(x=100, y=140)

#____________________________________________________________________
#FUNÇÃO - SELECIONAR LISTA
from tkinter import filedialog
def UploadLista(event=None):
    filenamelist = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Lista Selecionada', filenamelist)

    msg_selecionar = Label(janela, text= filenamelist )
    msg_selecionar.place(x=180, y=200)

#____________________________________________________________________
#FUNÇÃO - SELECIONAR DIRETÓRIO
from tkinter import filedialog
def UploadDir(event=None):
    filenamedir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print('Diretório Selecionado', filenamedir )

    msg_selecionar = Label(janela, text= filenamedir )
    msg_selecionar.place(x=199, y=242)


#____________________________________________________________________
#FUNÇÃO - SEPARAR
def bt_click_separar():
    traco()
    print ('Movendo Fotos...')
    traco()
    import os.path
    import shutil

    filenamelist = UploadDir

    arq = open(PRECISO COLOCAR O CAMINHO DA LISTA AQUI, 'r')
    dir_arquivo = ''

    for linha in arq:

        nomeantigo, novonome = linha.rstrip().split(';')
        dir_arquivo = os.path.dirname(nomeantigo)

        if  os.path.isdir('PRECISO COLOCAR O LOCAL DO DIRETÓRIO SELECIONADO + .\COMPLETO'): # verifica se este diretorio ja existe
            print ('-')
        else:
            os.mkdir('PRECISO COLOCAR O LOCAL DO DIRETÓRIO SELECIONADO + .\COMPLETO') # criar a pasta caso não exista
            print ('Pasta criada com sucesso!')

        if os.path.isfile(nomeantigo): # verifica se arquivo existe
            print ()
        else:
            print (' ')
            print (' ')
            print ('***ALERTA BOOK*** O arquivo do formando não está na pasta ----> ' , nomeantigo )
            print (' ')
            print (' ')
            lbseparar1 = Label(janela, text="***ALERTA BOOK*** Algum arquivo não está na pasta ou já foi movido.")
            lbseparar1.place(x=60, y=300)

            continue


        shutil.move(nomeantigo,'PRECISO COLOCAR LOCAL DO DIRETÓRIO SELECIONADO + .\COMPLETO')
        print (nomeantigo, 'Movido')


        lbseparar2 = Label(janela, text="Arquivos separados!")
        lbseparar2.place(x=80, y=280)

#____________________________________________________________________
#FUNÇÃO - RENOMEAR

def bt_click_renomear():

    traco()
    print('Renomeando Fotos...')
    traco()


    arq = open(PRECISO COLOCAR O CAMINHO DA LISTA AQUI, 'r')
    os.chdir(PRECISO COLOCAR O CAMINHO DO DIRETÓRIO AQUI)

    for linha in arq:
        nomeantigo, novonome = linha.rstrip().split(';')
        novonome = novonome.lower()
        novonome = novonome.replace(' ','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('_','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('- ','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('-- ','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('--','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('---','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('----','-')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ç','c')
        novonome = novonome.replace('á','a')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ã','a')
        novonome = novonome.replace('â','a')
        novonome = novonome.replace('é','e')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ê','e')
        novonome = novonome.replace('í','i')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ó','o')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ô','o')
        novonome = novonome.replace('ú','u')
        novonome = novonome.replace('meio-corpo','mc')
        novonome = novonome.replace('corpo-inteiro','ci')


        dir_arquivo = os.path.dirname(novonome)




        if os.path.isfile(nomeantigo): # verifica se arquivo existe
            print ('-')
        else:
            print (' ')
            print (' ')
            print ('***ALERTA BOOK*** O arquivo não está na pasta -------> ' , nomeantigo )
            print (' ')
            print (' ')
            lbrenomear1 = Label(janela, text="***ALERTA BOOK*** Algum arquivo não está na pasta ou já foi renomeado.")
            lbrenomear1.place(x=50, y=320)
            continue



        os.rename(nomeantigo, novonome)
        print(f'Arquivo {nomeantigo} renomeado para {novonome}')

        lbrenomear2 = Label(janela, text="Arquivos renomeados!")
        lbrenomear2.place(x=80, y=320)



#____________________________________________________________________
#BOTOES


#Separar
btseparar = Button(janela, width=20, text='Separar', command=bt_click_separar)
btseparar.place(x=80, y=550)


#Renomear
btrenomear = Button(janela, width=20, text='Renomear',             command=bt_click_renomear)
btrenomear.place(x=270, y=550)


#Selecionar Lista
selecionar_lista = tk.Button(janela, text='Selecionar Lista',     command=UploadLista)
selecionar_lista.place(x=80, y=200)


#Selecionar Diretório
selecionar_dir = tk.Button(janela, text='Selecionar Diretório', command=UploadDir)
selecionar_dir.place(x=80, y=240)


#____________________________________________________________________




janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi, seu problema é apenas obter o diretório para utilizar no `open`. Sendo assim basta você retornar o caminho na função `UploadDir` e `UploadLista`. Exemplo:

```
def UploadLista(event=None):
    filenamelist = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Lista Selecionada', filenamelist)

    msg_selecionar = Label(janela, text= filenamelist )
    msg_selecionar.place(x=180, y=200)
    return filenamelist
```

Depois disso, basta obter o retorno da função e utilizar o caminho dentro do `open`. Exemplo:

```
def bt_click_separar():
    traco()
    print ('Movendo Fotos...')
    traco()
    import os.path
    import shutil


    # Dúvida: Porque usou o UploadDir ao invés de UploadLista aqui ?
    # Como nesse trecho do código você disse que o objetivo era obter o
    # caminho do arquivo contendo a lista, eu tomei a liberdade 
    # de substituir UploadDir por UploadLista.

    filenamelist = UploadLista() # Obtém o retorno da função. 

    arq = open(filenamelist, 'r')

    # Resto do código...
```

Comment: Boa noite Jean!
Cara, estou com um outro "problema".
Fiz o que você disse, mas quando eu aciono o botão de separar ou renomear, ele pega o return da função inteira, abrindo uma janela pra escolher a lista e o diretório novamente.

Existe alguma possibilidade de isso não acontecer? E o return ser somente o resultado das funções?

Abraço!

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer mas vamos lá. Se você quer executar a função uma única vez, abrindo a janela para escolher um diretório e na próxima vez não precisar abrir a janela, você pode declarar a variável que obtém o diretório como global e utilizar uma condicional. Veja este código de exemplo: https://repl.it/repls/MiniatureFrighteningCryptos

Comment: Se minhas respostas foram úteis para você, você pode clicar em votar nessa seta para cima.

Comment: Vou tentar aplicar esse método no código, depois te retorno se deu certo. Sobre a votação da resposta, acho que ainda não consigo votar por ter um usuário feito a pouco tempo kk.